# Как называется одежда русалок

Tags: названия, терминология

Есть ли у этой одежды название, которое бы однозначно указывало именно на неё? Что это: платье, сорочка?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По виду похожи на славянских русалок, а те чаще всего рисовались в белых **рубахах**, иногда в сарафанах, но у Вас на рисунке именно рубаха - так называемое нижнее платье. https://web-kapiche.ru/177-slavyanskie-rusalki.html